# MYSQL statement can't figure out whats wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, syntax-error

I have created this join statement for a student schedule printout, i am new to sql and php and cannot figure out what i have done incorrectly. If anyone could help i would greatly appreciate it.. Thanks in advance...(p.s. i am sorry if this is a really basic question)...

```
mysql_select_db($database_newconn, $newconn);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT a.student_id AS "Student ID", f.name AS "Course Name", g.name AS "Lesson Name", g.date AS "Lesson Date", g.start_time AS "Lesson Start Time", g.end_time AS "Lesson End Time", CONCAT( h.first_name,' ', h.last_name) AS "Lesson Tutor" FROM student_table a JOIN enrollement_schedule_table b ON(a.id = b.student_id) JOIN course_table f ON(f.id = b.course_id) JOIN student_attendance_slot_table c ON(c.student_id = a.id) JOIN lesson_table g ON(g.id = c.lesson_id) JOIN tutor_table d ON(d.id = g.tutor_id) JOIN staff_table h ON(h.id = d.staff_id)";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $newconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

Comment: What error do you get? What doesn't work? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: You should switch your connection to mysqli or use PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_connect if you can.  Sorry, it's mandatory to say that on here, so I figured I would be the one to do so!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a quoting issue. Get rid of the quotes around your column aliases and use ticks

```
$query_Recordset1 = "
    SELECT a.student_id AS `Student ID`, 
        f.name AS `Course Name`, 
        g.name AS `Lesson Name`, 
        g.date AS `Lesson Date`, 
        g.start_time AS `Lesson Start Time`, 
        g.end_time AS `Lesson End Time`, 
        CONCAT( h.first_name,' ', h.last_name) AS `Lesson Tutor` 
        FROM student_table a 
        JOIN enrollement_schedule_table b ON(a.id = b.student_id) 
        JOIN course_table f ON(f.id = b.course_id) 
        JOIN student_attendance_slot_table c ON(c.student_id = a.id) 
        JOIN lesson_table g ON(g.id = c.lesson_id) 
        JOIN tutor_table d ON(d.id = g.tutor_id) 
        JOIN staff_table h ON(h.id = d.staff_id)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use back ticks for the fields in the query instead of double quotes. Check this:

```
SELECT 
a.student_id AS `Student ID`
, f.name AS `Course Name`
, g.name AS `Lesson Name`
, g.date AS `Lesson Date`
, g.start_time AS `Lesson Start Time`
, g.end_time AS `Lesson End Time`
, CONCAT(h.first_name, ' ', h.last_name) AS `Lesson Tutor` 
FROM
student_table a 
JOIN enrollement_schedule_table b 
ON (a.id = b.student_id) 
JOIN course_table f 
ON (f.id = b.course_id) 
JOIN student_attendance_slot_table c 
ON (c.student_id = a.id) 
JOIN lesson_table g 
ON (g.id = c.lesson_id) 
JOIN tutor_table d 
ON (d.id = g.tutor_id) 
JOIN staff_table h 
ON (h.id = d.staff_id) ;
```